# PHP: Get JSON Data from File, work with Data and Save it to new JSON File

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

I've been sitting for days over a problem for which I can't find a working solution. I actually also have no idea about PHP.

The project is to calculate Covid-19 incidences (7-day incidences) for different regions, for each day.

The data is in the following JSON format (nested):

```
[
  {
    "Datum": "2021-02-06 09:13",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5557,
        "Death": 120,
        "New_Cases": 60,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8021,
        "Death": 113,
        "New_Cases": 97,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4675,
        "Death": 73,
        "New_Cases": 98,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44773,
        "Death": 1584,
        "New_Cases": 407,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6097,
        "Death": 70,
        "New_Cases": 32,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6439,
        "Death": 244,
        "New_Cases": 81,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5983,
        "Death": 164,
        "New_Cases": 87,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8980,
        "Death": 270,
        "New_Cases": 71,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2696,
        "Death": 92,
        "New_Cases": 40,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10350,
        "Death": 151,
        "New_Cases": 123,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15560,
        "Death": 636,
        "New_Cases": 108,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2756,
        "Death": 80,
        "New_Cases": 23,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 17213,
        "Death": 232,
        "New_Cases": 236,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5639,
        "Death": 88,
        "New_Cases": 78,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8900,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 135,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 29301,
        "Death": 404,
        "New_Cases": 577,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14635,
        "Death": 356,
        "New_Cases": 110,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3671,
        "Death": 73,
        "New_Cases": 16,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7374,
        "Death": 148,
        "New_Cases": 73,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7762,
        "Death": 124,
        "New_Cases": 142,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18744,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 310,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2021-02-05 09:12",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5545,
        "Death": 119,
        "New_Cases": 62,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8006,
        "Death": 113,
        "New_Cases": 106,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4652,
        "Death": 73,
        "New_Cases": 92,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44720,
        "Death": 1578,
        "New_Cases": 426,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6088,
        "Death": 69,
        "New_Cases": 27,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6424,
        "Death": 243,
        "New_Cases": 79,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5965,
        "Death": 163,
        "New_Cases": 85,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8969,
        "Death": 270,
        "New_Cases": 70,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2692,
        "Death": 91,
        "New_Cases": 41,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10336,
        "Death": 150,
        "New_Cases": 126,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15547,
        "Death": 635,
        "New_Cases": 113,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2754,
        "Death": 79,
        "New_Cases": 24,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 17189,
        "Death": 231,
        "New_Cases": 241,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5625,
        "Death": 88,
        "New_Cases": 82,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8882,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 146,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 29217,
        "Death": 401,
        "New_Cases": 549,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14617,
        "Death": 356,
        "New_Cases": 120,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3668,
        "Death": 71,
        "New_Cases": 18,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7358,
        "Death": 148,
        "New_Cases": 66,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7743,
        "Death": 122,
        "New_Cases": 149,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18705,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 333,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2021-02-04 09:20",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5537,
        "Death": 118,
        "New_Cases": 68,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7987,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 110,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4636,
        "Death": 73,
        "New_Cases": 106,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44637,
        "Death": 1575,
        "New_Cases": 434,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6082,
        "Death": 69,
        "New_Cases": 29,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6416,
        "Death": 243,
        "New_Cases": 83,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5956,
        "Death": 163,
        "New_Cases": 86,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8961,
        "Death": 268,
        "New_Cases": 75,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2687,
        "Death": 91,
        "New_Cases": 45,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10314,
        "Death": 150,
        "New_Cases": 130,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15529,
        "Death": 629,
        "New_Cases": 113,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2747,
        "Death": 79,
        "New_Cases": 23,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 17147,
        "Death": 230,
        "New_Cases": 250,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5618,
        "Death": 88,
        "New_Cases": 95,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8869,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 166,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 29064,
        "Death": 401,
        "New_Cases": 476,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14588,
        "Death": 356,
        "New_Cases": 121,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3665,
        "Death": 71,
        "New_Cases": 24,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7340,
        "Death": 146,
        "New_Cases": 57,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7708,
        "Death": 122,
        "New_Cases": 144,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18665,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 339,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2021-02-03 09:44",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5527,
        "Death": 117,
        "New_Cases": 66,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7966,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 108,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4607,
        "Death": 73,
        "New_Cases": 93,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44555,
        "Death": 1570,
        "New_Cases": 407,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6074,
        "Death": 69,
        "New_Cases": 31,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6397,
        "Death": 243,
        "New_Cases": 73,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5930,
        "Death": 161,
        "New_Cases": 68,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8953,
        "Death": 268,
        "New_Cases": 73,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2681,
        "Death": 91,
        "New_Cases": 42,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10275,
        "Death": 149,
        "New_Cases": 105,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15511,
        "Death": 625,
        "New_Cases": 111,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2745,
        "Death": 78,
        "New_Cases": 23,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 17093,
        "Death": 229,
        "New_Cases": 234,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5597,
        "Death": 87,
        "New_Cases": 90,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8843,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 190,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 29042,
        "Death": 399,
        "New_Cases": 514,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14568,
        "Death": 356,
        "New_Cases": 131,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3659,
        "Death": 71,
        "New_Cases": 26,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7320,
        "Death": 146,
        "New_Cases": 52,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7666,
        "Death": 122,
        "New_Cases": 130,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18628,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 359,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2021-02-02 09:29",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5505,
        "Death": 117,
        "New_Cases": 55,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7931,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 91,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4596,
        "Death": 72,
        "New_Cases": 92,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44451,
        "Death": 1564,
        "New_Cases": 350,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6066,
        "Death": 69,
        "New_Cases": 27,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6379,
        "Death": 243,
        "New_Cases": 75,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5912,
        "Death": 160,
        "New_Cases": 59,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8934,
        "Death": 266,
        "New_Cases": 59,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2668,
        "Death": 91,
        "New_Cases": 32,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10244,
        "Death": 148,
        "New_Cases": 83,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15477,
        "Death": 623,
        "New_Cases": 83,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2740,
        "Death": 77,
        "New_Cases": 20,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 17053,
        "Death": 229,
        "New_Cases": 211,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5580,
        "Death": 87,
        "New_Cases": 82,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8821,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 190,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 28886,
        "Death": 397,
        "New_Cases": 407,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14541,
        "Death": 356,
        "New_Cases": 126,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3659,
        "Death": 70,
        "New_Cases": 29,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7297,
        "Death": 146,
        "New_Cases": 43,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7628,
        "Death": 122,
        "New_Cases": 104,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18539,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 318,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2021-02-01 09:30",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5500,
        "Death": 117,
        "New_Cases": 63,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7925,
        "Death": 111,
        "New_Cases": 100,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4577,
        "Death": 72,
        "New_Cases": 82,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44379,
        "Death": 1557,
        "New_Cases": 326,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6059,
        "Death": 69,
        "New_Cases": 24,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6372,
        "Death": 243,
        "New_Cases": 82,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5899,
        "Death": 160,
        "New_Cases": 60,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8926,
        "Death": 265,
        "New_Cases": 60,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2666,
        "Death": 91,
        "New_Cases": 32,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10231,
        "Death": 148,
        "New_Cases": 80,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15466,
        "Death": 622,
        "New_Cases": 87,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2739,
        "Death": 77,
        "New_Cases": 28,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 17013,
        "Death": 229,
        "New_Cases": 200,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5564,
        "Death": 87,
        "New_Cases": 81,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8791,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 188,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 28808,
        "Death": 395,
        "New_Cases": 400,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14522,
        "Death": 353,
        "New_Cases": 122,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3659,
        "Death": 70,
        "New_Cases": 45,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7289,
        "Death": 144,
        "New_Cases": 39,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7626,
        "Death": 122,
        "New_Cases": 127,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18509,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 325,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2021-01-31 09:12",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5498,
        "Death": 117,
        "New_Cases": 77,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7918,
        "Death": 109,
        "New_Cases": 120,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4574,
        "Death": 72,
        "New_Cases": 92,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44365,
        "Death": 1545,
        "New_Cases": 374,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6059,
        "Death": 69,
        "New_Cases": 32,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6372,
        "Death": 241,
        "New_Cases": 92,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5899,
        "Death": 159,
        "New_Cases": 78,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8924,
        "Death": 263,
        "New_Cases": 66,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2666,
        "Death": 91,
        "New_Cases": 34,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10231,
        "Death": 147,
        "New_Cases": 99,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15456,
        "Death": 622,
        "New_Cases": 96,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2739,
        "Death": 77,
        "New_Cases": 35,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 17011,
        "Death": 227,
        "New_Cases": 224,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5561,
        "Death": 87,
        "New_Cases": 91,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8788,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 223,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 28792,
        "Death": 391,
        "New_Cases": 454,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14513,
        "Death": 352,
        "New_Cases": 142,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3656,
        "Death": 70,
        "New_Cases": 50,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7283,
        "Death": 144,
        "New_Cases": 43,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7617,
        "Death": 122,
        "New_Cases": 137,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18504,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 364,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2021-01-30 09:20",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5483,
        "Death": 114,
        "New_Cases": 71,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7901,
        "Death": 108,
        "New_Cases": 132,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4564,
        "Death": 72,
        "New_Cases": 98,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44318,
        "Death": 1534,
        "New_Cases": 390,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6058,
        "Death": 69,
        "New_Cases": 38,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6371,
        "Death": 240,
        "New_Cases": 110,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5889,
        "Death": 158,
        "New_Cases": 80,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8918,
        "Death": 263,
        "New_Cases": 63,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2660,
        "Death": 91,
        "New_Cases": 36,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10213,
        "Death": 147,
        "New_Cases": 106,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15437,
        "Death": 618,
        "New_Cases": 90,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2737,
        "Death": 77,
        "New_Cases": 34,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 16966,
        "Death": 226,
        "New_Cases": 223,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5558,
        "Death": 86,
        "New_Cases": 111,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8782,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 256,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 28714,
        "Death": 390,
        "New_Cases": 445,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14496,
        "Death": 348,
        "New_Cases": 140,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3649,
        "Death": 70,
        "New_Cases": 48,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7281,
        "Death": 143,
        "New_Cases": 47,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7610,
        "Death": 122,
        "New_Cases": 162,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18485,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 395,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Datum": "2021-01-29 08:50",
    "Staates": [
      {
        "Cases": 5464,
        "Death": 113,
        "New_Cases": 65,
        "Region": "Region_A"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7880,
        "Death": 108,
        "New_Cases": 130,
        "Region": "Region_B"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 4545,
        "Death": 72,
        "New_Cases": 95,
        "Region": "Region_C"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 44238,
        "Death": 1522,
        "New_Cases": 398,
        "Region": "Region_D"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6050,
        "Death": 68,
        "New_Cases": 39,
        "Region": "Region_E"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 6352,
        "Death": 239,
        "New_Cases": 100,
        "Region": "Region_T"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5875,
        "Death": 158,
        "New_Cases": 84,
        "Region": "Region_U"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8910,
        "Death": 263,
        "New_Cases": 58,
        "Region": "Region_F"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2658,
        "Death": 91,
        "New_Cases": 38,
        "Region": "Region_G"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 10200,
        "Death": 146,
        "New_Cases": 116,
        "Region": "Region_H"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 15412,
        "Death": 613,
        "New_Cases": 85,
        "Region": "Region_I"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 2727,
        "Death": 76,
        "New_Cases": 30,
        "Region": "Region_J"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 16918,
        "Death": 225,
        "New_Cases": 228,
        "Region": "Region_K"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 5531,
        "Death": 86,
        "New_Cases": 122,
        "Region": "Region_L"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 8751,
        "Death": 112,
        "New_Cases": 266,
        "Region": "Region_M"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 28642,
        "Death": 389,
        "New_Cases": 479,
        "Region": "Region_N"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 14464,
        "Death": 347,
        "New_Cases": 134,
        "Region": "Region_O"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 3645,
        "Death": 70,
        "New_Cases": 54,
        "Region": "Region_P"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7268,
        "Death": 143,
        "New_Cases": 45,
        "Region": "Region_Q"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 7574,
        "Death": 121,
        "New_Cases": 147,
        "Region": "Region_R"
      },
      {
        "Cases": 18435,
        "Death": 10,
        "New_Cases": 404,
        "Region": "Region_S "
      }
    ]
  },
 { ............ }
]
```

The data in the file goes back to 03/15/2020.

From these data, I want to calculate the 7-day incidences for each region for each date.

Example Region A (7-day incidenc on 2021-02-06):

New cases in the last 7 days:

60 + 62 + 68 + 66 + 55 + 63 + 77
= 451 / 7 = 64,42... (round to 64.4)

The data should now be saved in a new JSON file as follows.

```
[
    {   "ID": 1,       // Unique ID for each region (e.g. ID 1 for Region_A). There are 21 regions.
        "Datum": "2021-02-06 09:13",
        "Staat": "Region_A",
        "New_Cases": 60,
        "Seven_Days_Incidenc": 64.4,
        "Trend": "Down"   // Trend to the 7-day incidence of the previous day
    },
    {
        "ID": 2,
        "Datum": "2021-02-06 09:13",
        "Staat": "Region_B",
        "New_Cases": 97,
        "Seven_Days_Incidenc": 104.6,
        "Trend": "Up"
    },
    {
        "ID": 3,
        "Datum": "2021-02-06 09:13",
        "Staat": "Region_C",
        "New_Cases": 98,
        "Seven_Days_Incidenc": 93.6,
        "Trend": "Up"
    },
    { ..... }
]
```

I can get the data from the json file, but I can't get the calculation to work, and I can't get the correct output to a new JSON file.

Additionally I want to assign a fixed ID for each region. This works already.

The following PHP code I have (is probably totally wrong this approach):

```
<?php

$jsonALL= file_get_contents('covid-19-all.json');

$jsonData = json_decode($jsonALL, TRUE);

        $x = 1;
        $length = count($jsonData);
        $days = 7;
        $countDays = 0;
        
        $json_array_target  =   array();
        $json_array_sieben_tage_inzidenz  =   array();

            foreach($jsonData as $data) {
                $countDays++;
                $datum = $data['Datum'];
                    foreach($data['Staates'] as $key => $value) {

                        
                        /* Testing
                        $json_array_target['Datum'] = $datum;
                        $json_array_target['Region'] = $value['Region'];
                        $json_array_target['Neue Faelle'] = $value['New_Cases'];
                        */

                        $json_array_sieben_tage_inzidenz[] = ['ID' => $key + 1, 'Datum' => $datum, 'Region' => $value['Region'], 'Neue Faelle' => $value['New_Cases'], 'Summe' => $sum+= $value['New_Cases'] ];
                    

                    }
                    
                    
                if ($countDays == $days) break;

                
            }
            
            // View JSON Data on Screen
            echo json_encode($json_array_sieben_tage_inzidenz, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) . "<br>";
            file_put_contents('covid-19-seven-days-incidenc-data.json', $json_array_sieben_tage_inzidenz);


?>
```

I hope someone can help me with this. Should the implementation be more complex than I assumed, I am also willing to pay something for it, it should not fail. It is a project for a non-profit association of which I am a member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simplified version, you can extend by your needs.

I use OOP to make it easy to handle.

```php
class Region implements JsonSerializable
{
    public $id    = 0;
    public $date  = '';
    public $state = '';

    private $values = [];

    public function addValue(int $value)
    {
        $this->values[] = $value;
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return [
            'id'                 => $this->id,
            'state'              => $this->state,
            'SevenDaysIncidence' => round($this->getSevenDaysIncidence(), 1),
            'trend'              => $this->getTrend(),
            'newCases'           => $this->values[0] ?? 0,
            'date'               => $this->date,
        ];
    }

    private function getSevenDaysIncidence()
    {
        if (!count($this->values)) {
            return 0;
        }
        return array_sum(array_slice($this->values, 0, 7)) / min(7, count($this->values));
    }

    private function getTrend()
    {
        if (count($this->values) < 2 || $this->values[0] > $this->values[1]) {
            return 'Up';
        }
        if ($this->values[0] < $this->values[1]) {
            return 'Down';
        }

        return 'Equal';
    }
}

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('covid-19-all.json'));

$regions = [];
$id      = 1;

foreach ($input as $data) {
    foreach ($data->Staates as $state) {
        if (!isset($regions[$state->Region])) {
            $region                  = new Region();
            $region->state           = $state->Region;
            $region->id              = $id++;
            $region->date            = $data->Datum;
            $regions[$state->Region] = $region;
        } else {
            $region = $regions[$state->Region];
        }
        $region->addValue($state->New_Cases);
    }
}

$output = json_encode(array_values($regions), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
echo $output;
```

You may save the contents into a file like

```
file_put_contents('myJSON.json', $output);
```

The output looks like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "state": "Region_A",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 64.4,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 60,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "state": "Region_B",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 104.6,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 97,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "state": "Region_C",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 93.6,
        "trend": "Up",
        "newCases": 98,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "state": "Region_D",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 389.1,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 407,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "state": "Region_E",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 28.9,
        "trend": "Up",
        "newCases": 32,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "state": "Region_T",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 80.7,
        "trend": "Up",
        "newCases": 81,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "state": "Region_U",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 74.7,
        "trend": "Up",
        "newCases": 87,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "state": "Region_F",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 67.7,
        "trend": "Up",
        "newCases": 71,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "state": "Region_G",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 38,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 40,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "state": "Region_H",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 106.6,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 123,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "state": "Region_I",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 101.6,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 108,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "state": "Region_J",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 25.1,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 23,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "state": "Region_K",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 228,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 236,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "state": "Region_L",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 85.6,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 78,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 15,
        "state": "Region_M",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 176.9,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 135,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 16,
        "state": "Region_N",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 482.4,
        "trend": "Up",
        "newCases": 577,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "state": "Region_O",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 124.6,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 110,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 18,
        "state": "Region_P",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 29.7,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 16,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 19,
        "state": "Region_Q",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 53.3,
        "trend": "Up",
        "newCases": 73,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 20,
        "state": "Region_R",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 133.3,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 142,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "state": "Region_S",
        "SevenDaysIncidence": 335.4,
        "trend": "Down",
        "newCases": 310,
        "date": "2021-02-06 09:13"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick and detailed answer.

I have two questions:

1. where do I have to put the path to the file, isn't there something missing?
`$input= file_get_contents('covid-19-all.json');`
or something like that. Where would I have to insert this?

2. the output of the JSON file must be like in my example above (no nested objects). Otherwise the data can not be processed by the used software.

I hope you can give me some help here.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I just copied the data you provided as an string. But yes, you can `$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('covid-19-all.json'));`

Comment: Where do you see nested objects? It is just an Array containing the objects exactly as you told you wanted your output.

Comment: Nevertheless, thanks for your help, then we have to look for a programmer. Thanks

Comment: I've downgraded the code to PHP7.3. Try again.

Comment: Thank you, I just figured it out myself, after changing the definition of the variables it now works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Excuse me Mr. Zeller, could I possibly ask you again for help. I just can't get the whole json file to be processed. I mean that all dates with the associated regions are read out, I always manage only the first date and the associated regions. Is there a possibility here, or is that too complex? Thank you very much.